# What could be causing distorted audio when streaming audio from Blazor to the Web Audio API?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

Streaming Generated Audio from Blazor (via invokeMethodAsync) to the Web Audio API (AudioWorkletNode)

something is seriously wrong with the sound being produced (its like a machine gun with other distortions)

I am attempting to use invokeMethodAsync in the main thread javascript side to invoke a function in blazor wasm that returns two channels of float arrays. Then send it on to the worklet processor thread.
The Web app feels very responsive using a midi input (using an interop as well) with very little latency. But the sound im getting is very distorted

Where could the problem be:

1. the wave generation in C# -

```
        
        [JSInvokable("ProcessAudioData")]
        public float[][] ProcessAudioData()
        {
            float[] leftSamples = new float[bufferSize];
            float[] rightSamples = new float[bufferSize];


            for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
            {
                float mixedSample = 0.0f;


                foreach (var note in activeNotes)
                {
                    int noteKey = note.Key;
                    float frequency = (float)note.Value;
                    float amplitude = (float)activeAmplitudes[noteKey];
                    float phaseIncrement = (float)(2.0 * Math.PI * frequency / sampleRate);

                    mixedSample += (float)(amplitude * Math.Sin(phase));
                    phase += phaseIncrement;

                }

                // Clamp value between -1 and 1 to avoid clipping
                mixedSample = (float)Math.Max(-1.0, Math.Min(1.0, mixedSample));

                // Assign the mixed sample to the appropriate index in the left and right sample arrays
                leftSamples[i] = mixedSample;
                rightSamples[i] = mixedSample;


            }

            // Return the arrays in a 2D array
            return new[] { leftSamples, rightSamples };
        }
```

2. Recieving 2D Array in JS main thread -

```
async function setupAudioNode(audioSwitch, instrumentReference) {
    const bufferSize = 128;
    const numberOfChannels = 2;
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();

    console.log('Create audioWorklet');
    console.log('audioContext:', audioContext);

    const sharedBufferSize = bufferSize * numberOfChannels * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    const sharedBuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(sharedBufferSize);

    const stateBuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(4); // Holds one Int32
    const stateIntArray = new Int32Array(stateBuffer);


    audioSwitch.audioContext = audioContext;

    await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('/AudioNode/AudioProcessor.js');

    if (instrumentReference) {
        const workletNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'audio-worklet-processor', {
            numberOfOutputs: 1,
            outputChannelCount: [2],
            channelCountMode: 'explicit',
            channelInterpretation: 'speakers',
            processorOptions: { sharedBuffer, stateBuffer }
        });
        workletNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

        // Resume the audio context
        await audioContext.resume();
        console.log('audioContext state:', audioContext.state);



        async function sendAudioData() {

            if (Atomics.load(stateIntArray, 0) === 0) { // 0 - buffer is ready, 1 - buffer is consumed

                // Get the float arrays directly from the .NET method
                const audioData = await instrumentReference.invokeMethodAsync('ProcessAudioData');

                const leftFloatArray = new Float32Array(audioData[0]);
                const rightFloatArray = new Float32Array(audioData[1]);

                // Fill SharedArrayBuffer
                new Float32Array(sharedBuffer, 0, bufferSize).set(leftFloatArray);
                new Float32Array(sharedBuffer, bufferSize * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, bufferSize).set(rightFloatArray);

                // Set the state to "ready"
                Atomics.store(stateIntArray, 0, 1);
                Atomics.notify(stateIntArray, 0, 1); // Notify the worklet that the state has changed            
            }

            // Schedule the next audio data fetch
            setTimeout(sendAudioData, bufferSize / audioContext.sampleRate * 1000);
        }




        // Start fetching audio data
        sendAudioData();


        audioSwitch.workletNode = workletNode;
    }

    return audioContext;
}
```

3. Between the main thread and Worklet Processor thread -

```
class AudioProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
        console.log("AudioProcessor created");
        this.sharedBuffer = options.processorOptions.sharedBuffer;
        this.stateBuffer = options.processorOptions.stateBuffer
        this.stateIntArray = new Int32Array(this.stateBuffer);
        this.leftData = new Float32Array(this.sharedBuffer, 0, 128);
        this.rightData = new Float32Array(this.sharedBuffer, 128 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 128);

    }

    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        if (Atomics.load(this.stateIntArray, 0) === 1) {
            const outputBuffer = outputs[0];

            outputBuffer[0].set(this.leftData);
            outputBuffer[1].set(this.rightData);


            // Set the state to "consumed"
            Atomics.store(this.stateIntArray, 0, 0);


        }
        // return false if no data is available yet to keep the processor alive

        return true;
    }
}


registerProcessor('audio-worklet-processor', AudioProcessor);
```

ideally i would want to call the c# code from a web worker then share the data via sharedArrayBuffer between the threads - i think might be available in the future in .net 8
I could be doing something very stupid here and it might be impossible, i am very new. Any insight would be much appreciated.
and happy to give more infomation.

Comment: So in order to pinpoint the issue... at step1, when you get the byte array from their web worker - does it play normally when you save it, or is it also distorted?